# Why is my Android phone not receiving text messages from certain contacts?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, sms, bugs

I'm in the UK.

My phone:

- Samsung Galaxy A3 (SM-A300FU)
- Android 5.0.2
- three.co.uk branded Android & SIM

The symptoms have been detected for these contact situations:

1. Swiss phone (unknown make/model) in Switzerland
2. Swiss Android phone in Australia
3. Norwegian iPhone in the UK

In all these cases the contacts have told me via other channels that they have tried to send me SMSes, and these have not come through. It looks like this has been going on since at least early August. I *have* been able to receive automated SMSes from a company in Norway in the meantime, and I've not detected problems with UK numbers, so not all numbers are broken.

---

Today I spoke with Three support, and I was told a very puzzling workaround which actually helped: **Delete the contact** before sending any more messages! This worked for one contact which tried many times before to send SMSes, but now I'm worried:

1. Why would my phone stop receiving messages in the first place?
2. Why on Earth would deleting the contact fix it?
3. How can I detect if this happens again? I can't keep sending ping messages to all my contacts on a regular basis.
4. Is there a more reliable messaging application than the built-in Android one?

Comment: I think you should address the second question to the three.co.uk support. One thing I think was an issue for me some time ago - in order to be able to receive SMS, your mobile network provider and the sender's mobile network provider should have made a mutual contract. Unfortunately I cannot provide facts for this...

Comment: After "resolving" this with Three they insisted that it was not an issue on their side - the number was simply stored "incorrectly" (sic) on my phone. I'm inclined to think that they are right, since deleting the contact on my phone was enough to fix at least the immediate symptom.